# Download the default document in IIS10

Tags: iis, directory-index

That's pretty much it. I want to have IIS push the default document to browsers instead of making them parse it.

I have a ton of these nano-sites in subdomains so they're easy to remember; currently I deal with it with HAProxy rules or I set the default document in a simple, clean web page that meta-refres*es into the file needed. It looks pretty good just a good ol' fashioned invisible single-cell table with a pinch of CSS. 1KB. Zero JavaScript and it has always worked but I keep finding references here and there that it's *not* okay to use *meta-refresh* anymore.

I think it's being/was phased out and it will start getting blocked by browsers any minute now. I want to have this covered at least in regards of the servers I use; httpd is fairly straighforward. NGINX and others I actively avoid, but being in a Active Directory domain plus the familiarity of the GUI makes IIS unavoidable. Not to mention shared configuration, centralcerts, DFS namespaces/replication, etc.

I hope it doesn't involve changing MIME types but I'll be grateful either way.

Update:
I thought it was clear but by elaborating I did the opposite, it seems. My bad.

I didn't mean "Push", the technology, but rather just "push" like a salesman or relentless spouse/mother pressuring for something would do: hint the browser to download/save (like a MIME type `application/x-zip-compressed`, for instance) instead making the browser show the page (i.e. [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) it) as it would normally happen with HTML (or, as you know, text/html MIME type files) if the file is something parsable client-side. I want grandchildren already.

The cell and meta tags are unrelated to each other, the cell is to give space out the page centering and image with the tiniest bit of CSS. `meta http-equiv="refresh"` then `<del>loads</del>` "pushes" a file or redirects. A big part of this is Apache httpd, which allows to single out stuff through .ht* files. It's less than 20 lines total, loads instantly and just needs changing target sometimes the image, less often `.htaccess`. Here one of them I grabbed at random I don't remember what it's supposed to do, I think it was just a template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>This page has never existed. Redirecting… - VitaNetworks Web Services</title>
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=https://index.vi..." /> //-->
</head><body style="background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); background-position: center; background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<div style="text-align: center;">
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"> <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjwhRE9DVFlQRSBzdmcgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBTVkcgMS4xLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL0dyYXBoaWNzL1NWRy8xLjEvRFREL3N2ZzExLmR0ZCI+Cjxzdmcgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDc2NyA0ODAiIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSIgeG1sbnM6c2VyaWY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2VyaWYuY29tLyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGwtcnVsZTpldmVub2RkO2NsaXAtcnVsZTpldmVub2RkO3N0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbjpyb3VuZDtzdHJva2UtbWl0ZXJsaW1pdDoyOyI+CiAgICA8cmVjdCBpZD0iYmxhbmsiIHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSI3NjciIGhlaWdodD0iNDgwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lOyIvPgo8L3N2Zz4K" title="Some blank placeholder or…" alt="…description for accesibility makeshift medium" style="width: 767px; height: 100%;" align="middle" hspace="0" vspace="0"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
&nbsp;
</div>
</body></html>
```

I'm open to anything though. Ideally I'd love something  that if requesting the domain with no file indication via `curl` (e.g; curl -o|wget -O file_thingv201 http://...com), would end up downloading the same file invoked by the `index.html` or equivalent but I'm more than content by just getting some of the simplicity of `httpd` in the MMC snap-in of IIS.

Software version(s): Windows Server 2022 with IIS 10.0.20378.169. With modules Application Request Routing 3.5, URL Rewrite 2.0 installed. No Ruby/PHP/Python/Node.js, Java Applet server or other managed code has been installed (except for ASP.NET bc it comes with IIS) pages are pages, not web apps.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm not sure what you mean by "push the default document".  Web server typically respond with the default document when a client requests the default URL.  There is very little "push" in HTTP.  The only pushes come with websockets or resources that come with documents in HTTP/2

Comment: What do you mean by "instead of making them parse it?"   When you serve a document to a client, it is ALWAYS parsed into a document object model (DOM.)  There is no way to prevent that that I know of.

Comment: Can you share more about your meta refresh? Can you share some example code?  I'm not sure how a table cell would be useful with it.  Maybe you mean a frameset or iframe?

Comment: You want to make it so that when the web page is viewed, it automatically triggers the download of a file?